# Call a method from a Python object

Tags: python, class, methods

So I have this class written in Python with a constructor that takes a string as an argument when initialized. This class has a method for reversing the same string that was taken as an argument, but am not able to instantiate this class into an object and call the method like in other languages. Please help

```
class Palindrome:
   ##Constructor for taking string argument
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.myname=name
    def func(myname):
        return (myname[::-1])
##Take a string as a argument from user and use it in the constructor
uname=input("Enter name to reverse?")
##Trying to call method from a python object
Palindrome mypalidrome=Palindrome(uname)
print(mypalindrome.func)
```

The above `print(mypalindrome.func)` is outputting this instead

```
<bound method Palindrome.func of <__main__.Palindrome object at 0x00221F10>>
```

Comment: You sure you wrote this correct : `Palindrome mypalidrome=Palindrome(uname)` ?

Comment: I think you need some parentheses and an argument: `print(mypalindrome.func(uname))`. Also, you're not actually using `self.myname` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code `mypalindrome` has a typo and func should have `self` as parameter. Also function is called with `()` here is the working solution

```
class Palindrome:
   ##Constructor for taking string argument
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.myname=name
    def func(self):
        return (self.myname[::-1])
##Take a string as a argument from user and use it in the constructor
uname=input("Enter name to reverse?")
mypalindrome =Palindrome(uname)
print(mypalindrome.func())
```